# Definitive list of everything a entry level network or unix admin must know

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job)

I am interested in a list which would recommend what you feel is absolutely necessary for somebody who is looking for a entry level position as a network or unix admin, possibly windows also.

Is there a single book that can help one get started, maybe a CCNA book.

Comment: Basically this is a dup of of http://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Network Management & Support
- Confident within the command line
- Understanding the TCP stack

I could go on... but in truth you may be better going to a job website and having a look there, as this list can change from company to company depending on what is important to them.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to configure and maintain -

Firewall - Proxy - DNS - Mail Server - Web Server - DB Server - Print & File Services - Network Monitoring

and do it REMOTELY :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a definitive list as being even possible; I would second the advice to look at some some job adverts and tally up the skill sets they're looking for.

For an entry level post we're probably looking at a tape monkey role, or perhaps monitoring cron jobs, or performing some other basic jobs.  Being comfortable with and curious about your environment, and knowing when to call for help when you're in over your head are the two I would select.