# New to systems administration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

My company has the following setup

Windows 2003 Small Business Server (SP2) running Exchange and Symantec Endpoint
Windows Server 2008 Standard (SP2) running SQL Server 2008 and Active Directory

The tech who was managing this left the company, leaving me to manage this on my own. I have no experience in managing servers but I would like to learn. Any suggestions on books or other resources that I could use to teach me how to effectively manage this?

Comment: Have you read [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job](http://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job) and the pages it links to?

Comment: I will take a look at that thread.

Comment: What Zoredache said.  Best thread ever (on this topic anyway).

Answer (score 2):

[The Practice of Systems and Network Administration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321492668) is a little Unix-slanted, but a great start on the generics of being a system/network administrator for everything and nothing in particular. Once you have the basics down of the platform you're trying to manage, this is a great step in the right direction for best-practices stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Minasi's books are pretty safe bets for windows administration

Answer (score 0):

http://serverfault.com

You're already there :)

If you feel like it plan to take a Microsoft certification or even a single exam about windows server deployment and management: it'll seriously help.