# What qualifications are required for a fresher to be a system administrator?

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job)

I am a student and want to be a system administrator. But I don't know that what types of qualification are expected from a fresher.

Answer (score 1):

I went straight in to a school working alongside system admins with a completely unrelated degree. Basic knowledge of things such as Active Directory, Windows Server 2003-2008 and Exchange 2003-2010 should help you get some way towards a training position. I don't believe it's worth jumping straight in as a system admin, maybe look at doing some technician work for one and work your way up. Maybe your university has a department in which you could volunteer?