# I am now leasing a Win 2008 server; what steps should I take (remote desktop, etc.)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, remote-desktop, visual-studio

I am completely new to this; in the past, I could make a simple site in Visual Studio and use ws_ftp to upload files to the server.  But now, we're leasing our own server from 1and1, and here's what they said:

"**you actually lease a server from us. You will need to either administer the server directly through Remote Desktop or take advantage of your Parallels Small Business Panel. Your operating system is Windows Web Server 2008. I do not know if the server comes preinstalled with asp.net 4.0, but you do have full administrator access to your server and can install any necessary software.**"

My goal is to make a small website in Visual Studio / vb / asp.net 4.0.

I really don't even know what a "server" is, but could anybody offer any basic simple steps that I'll need to do now that I have my own server?  I'm confused about what I need to download in order to manipulate the server (remote desktop, parallels small business panel, etc.).

So any guidance anybody could offer me, like some simple, basic steps I need to take, or the difference between now and when I used to just have a website hosted on one of theier servers would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Your question is overly-broad.  You are probably going to need to start by doing some research on your own first.  Maybe start here.  http://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job

Comment: Thanks you for the link, Zored.  In the meantime, I'll try to  narrow the question down.   Thanks!

Comment: I've marked your question down because it's not for this forum. If you don't know what a 'server' is, I recommend moving this question to SuperUser.

Comment: Out of interest, why have you chosen to lease (VPS, decicated?) server rather than using shared hosting (like previously?)

Comment: Not meant to be offensive in anyway, Jason, I hope you understand that. I simply mean that this particular site is for IT professionals, people who work on servers and networks everyday. SuperUser is geared towards computer enthusiasts who want to learn more. You don't have to move the question, if approved the admins will migrate it automatically.

Comment: I understand John; no offense was taken ... I just posted in the wrong forum, and I appreciate you helping me out and guiding me in the proper direction!

Comment: @JohnThePro, this question, as currently written is likely to get closed as over-broad on any site.  It seems to me has basically asked the equivalent of 'how do you program' or 'how do you build a computer', which would have been closed on stackoverflow, and superuser.

Comment: A heads up for you Jason, just to get you started, when you got your server, they also assigned you an IP. Most VPS servers have remote desktop enabled by default, so to get into your server to start with, you use the IP address that your hosting company provided, open Remote Desktop, and type in the IP address. If it is configured correctly, you should be prompted for a username and password (which your hosting company should also provide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you access your server is up to you FTP and remote desktop are the most common tools for this. Microsoft 2008 Server does not come with a default mail server you can use for pop3. You may need to look at something like this http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1678

IIS will need to be configured... link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972

If you open the Parallels Small Business Panel you should be able to configure a lot of this without needing Microsoft Server 2008 knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I only know hostgator so I don't know how the company you are using do things but I would stay away from the the remote desktop until you have a bit more server admin knowledge. Maybe buy a book?

Access to the server would be through a webpage, they most likely gave you a url to visit?

Choose a really good password, http://www.pctools.com/guides/password/

and use the business panel via that webpage; I think as long as you don't do anything silly its hard to screw things up too bad using that. From there you will be able to upload files and administer the server.