# Self-manage a Windows VPS

Tags: vps, windows-server-2012, windows

I have been looking into VPS web hosting, and there is quite a difference in price between self-managed and managed plans.

I've done some tinkering on IIS (using IIS Manager) but do not have any experience managing a server (though you have to start somewhere, don't you?).

I have a working web site that I've created (asp.net/C#) and is currently on shared hosting. I'm thinking of transferring it to a VPS.

So - Is it realistic to manage my own VPS? Or, rephrased, what would the main obstacles be?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/9766

Comment: possible duplicate of [What a beginner should know/learn for sysadmin job?](http://serverfault.com/questions/9766/what-a-beginner-should-know-learn-for-sysadmin-job)

Answer (score 8):

> So - Is it realistic to manage my own VPS?

Yes.

> Or, rephrased, what would the main obstacles be?

The fact that you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: The **upvote** button's pop-up is "This answer is useful". Hmmmmm...

Comment: Perhaps if you read the "Help" link at the top of this site, you would understand the context.

Comment: "What topics can I ask about here?

Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity."

Comment: Given your lacking professional capacity - none. SUperuser.com is for end users. A professional will tell you you are way over your head and that IS helpfull. You also dont try to design and build a car without knowing what you are doing. Or fly a plane.